# Why do I need two functions for dice rolling simulator?

Tags: python-3.x, random, dice

I've made a simply dice rolling simulator but afterwards, when looking at other people's examples, they've generally created two functions (Main to define the range 1 - 6, and a roll_dice function). Is it ok as I've done it? To me, the other versions seem more complex (with a while loop for example) without any extra functionality.

My code:

```
import random

def roll_dice():
    for x in range(1):
        print("You rolled a", (random.randint(1, 6)),"!")
        roll_again = input("Would you like to roll again? (Y or N): ")
        if roll_again.lower() == "y":
        roll_dice()
        if roll_again.lower() == "n":
            print("Thanks for rolling. See you next time")
        else:
            roll_again = input("Would you like to roll again? (Y or N): ")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yours is recursive so eventually you'll run out of stack. Also, if somebody enters `a`, then your else will get called, but not matter.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this for an assignment, and when you're referring to "other people's examples", are you talking about how classmates coded their solutions?

Comment: I'm just practicing on my own. "Other people's examples" from Google searches

Comment: Gotcha. As a heads up, you might get better answers on codereview.stackexchange.com; it sounds like that's essentially what you're asking for. I _will_ day though that it looks like you have an indentation problem in your `roll_dice()` (along with the things that @matt mentioned)

Comment: What's the `for x in range(1):` for? :D

Comment: @Jeronimo I thought `for x in range(1)` meant that only one number will be selected from the `randint(1, 6)`... Is there a better way to put it? :/ Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Forrence Didn't know of codereview.stackexchange.com! Great advice! Thanks :D

Comment: @sim No, it does absolutely nothing there. You could leave it away and dedent the whole block inside of it without any consequences.

Comment: I think that this is opinion-based, @sim, but to give an example why there could be two functions, [here's](https://gist.github.com/chrisforrence/042ccbb088dd6e526f01e59a1736be17) how I'd solve it. Basically, I'd separate out the concerns of rolling from the concern with interacting with the roller. Plus side is that it'd be easy to change it to do different dice, different rolls, etc.